# How to merge sql outputs into one dataframe

Tags: python

I have a list of SQL queries I would like to run, and have all of their outputs in one dataframe. The structure of the SQL outputs are all the same (1x1, just showing a count). So I would like the dataframe to be one row by x number of columns (representing the number of SQL checks). Below is what I have so far, but I have hit a wall. Any help with this would be extremely appreciated!

```
sqls = ['sql1.sql', 'sql2.sql']

query_results = []

for sql in sqls:
    with open(sql) as file:
        query = file.read()
        df_sql_output = pd.read_sql_query(query,conn)
        #query_results.append(pd.read_sql_query(query,conn))
print(df_sql_output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas `concat` method. Make sure all the dataframes have same column name.

```
import pandas as pd
df_sql_output = pd.concat(query_results)
```